# Find the volume of solid that lies under $z=x^2+y^2$, the $xy$ plane and inside $x^2+y^2=2x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of solid that lies under $z=x^2+y^2$, the $xy$ plane and inside $x^2+y^2=2x$

My attempt:

$z = x^2+y^2 = r^2= 2x$, and $x=rcos(\theta)$, so $r^2=2rcos(\theta),$

$r = 2cos(\theta)$

$\int{_{?}^{?}\int{_{0}^{2cos\theta} (x^2+y^2)r drd\theta}}$

I'm stuck on finding the bounds for $\theta$. Is it from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$?

Comment: I believe $\theta$ would have to range from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. This comes from the fact that $x^2+y^2=2x$ is more intuitively written as $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, a circle. Graphing this circle in the plane makes it clear that there are points on the circle at every angle $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$ but no points outside of this region (that is, to the left of the y-axis).

Comment: @NathanielB - This is the correct answer. If you want to answer this question I'll mark it right.  However, I'm still confused as to why it matters there are no points to the left of y-axis.  When working with polar coordinates, we are only concerned with the x and y axess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta$ would have to range from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. This comes from the fact that  is more intuitively written as $(x−1)^2+y^2=1$, a circle. Graphing this circle in the plane makes it clear that there are points on the circle at every angle $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$ but no points outside of this region (that is, in the range $\pi/2<\theta<3\pi/2$).

P.S. With respect to your comment regarding the y-axis, it is merely that the region of the plane $x<0$ can also be written as $\pi/2<\theta<3\pi/2$ if we assume that $r>0$.

Reasoning: $x<0\Leftrightarrow r\cos\theta<0\Leftrightarrow \cos\theta<0 \Leftrightarrow \pi/2<\theta<3\pi/2$ if we assume $0\leq\theta<2\pi$.